# How can I execute "Create table query" from the .sql (mysqldump) file using python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-redshift, database-migration

### Description

I am trying to create a python script that connects the AWS redshift cluster db and create same tables with same structure that are in mysql database. As I have 5 tables in current mysql db and don't want to create each table manually one-by-one, so try this using python script.

For this i have created a mysqldump file of database (mydb) using

```
mysqldump -d -u username -p mydb > mydb.sql
```

with no data bcoz i have exported the data in seprate csv files.
and the output is:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: classicmodels
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `customers`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customers`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditLimit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`),
  KEY `salesRepEmployeeNumber` (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `employees`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employees`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employeeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `reportsTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeNumber`),
  KEY `reportsTo` (`reportsTo`),
  KEY `officeCode` (`officeCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reportsTo`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`officeCode`) REFERENCES `offices` (`officeCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `offices`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `offices`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `offices` (
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `territory` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`officeCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `orderdetails`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orderdetails`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `orderdetails` (
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `quantityOrdered` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priceEach` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `orderLineNumber` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderNumber`,`productCode`),
  KEY `productCode` (`productCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `orderdetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`orderNumber`) REFERENCES `orders` (`orderNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `orderdetails_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`productCode`) REFERENCES `products` (`productCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `orders`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orderDate` date NOT NULL,
  `requiredDate` date NOT NULL,
  `shippedDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text,
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderNumber`),
  KEY `customerNumber` (`customerNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerNumber`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customerNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `payments`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `payments`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `checkNumber` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `paymentDate` date NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`,`checkNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `payments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerNumber`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customerNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `productlines`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `productlines`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `productlines` (
  `productLine` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `textDescription` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `htmlDescription` mediumtext,
  `image` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productLine`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `productCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `productLine` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `productScale` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `productVendor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `productDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `quantityInStock` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `buyPrice` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `MSRP` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productCode`),
  KEY `productLine` (`productLine`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`productLine`) REFERENCES `productlines` (`productLine`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### Code

just stated with sample code(incomplete) to check whether i able to create table in redshift db, which is working fine...

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host='mydb.mydatabase.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    user='user',
    port=5439,
    password='password',
    dbname='example_db')

cur = conn.cursor()
statement="CREATE TABLE table1 (name)"
cur.execute(statement)
conn.commit()
```

### Problem:

I am stuck in "how can i execute only the sql queries from `mydb.sql` ?" for creating the tables in aws redshift database.
How can i itrate over the mydb.sql file for creating the dbs ignoring the other lines. Any logic for this?

If I am somewhere wrong please correct me.

Please suggest any solution for this or any other way in which i can create same table using program for migrating the db with same schema.
I am just refering this URL: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/python-create-table.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be assuming that a SQL script for a MySQL database will run without modification on Redshift, which is unlikely to be true. As Jon said in his answer, there are AWS tools provided to migrate data and schemas from one database platform to another, I strongly recommend using these instead of trying to roll your own. Good table design is a key part of using Redshift effectively so you should think about things like distribution keys and sort keys for the Redshift tables, which will not be covered by a script derived from a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

AWS provide tools to do what you need, these might be better. Apologies if you have dismissed these already

1 - AWS DMS 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/#lang/en_us
This will create target tables for you, but also migrate your data

2 - AWS Schema Conversion Tool
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html